# why does count return 22 instead of 11?

Tags: php

This is my php script

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE perID=2");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$a = count($row);                     // or sizeof($row)
echo $a;       //outputs 22 but i expect it to be 11 but why does it output 22 ?
```

This is the data in mysql.

```
perID   one    two   three   four    five    six    sev    eit   nine  ten
  2    1.jpg  2.jpg  3.jpg   4.jpg   5.jpg  6.jpg  7.jpg  8.jpg  9.jpg 10.jpg
```

I expect it to be 11 but surprisingly its 22. Could anyone explain me why? Does it also include the 'one' 'two' (the column names) stuff too in the count function ? because it would be 22, if only if it includes them.

But it should not include the column part of table as they are headers right?  please help me with these Any help is greatly appreciated

also please give me a link or the way to achieve 11 as result

Comment: Thanks for all your answers how to solve these then ? how would i get 11 should i divide it by 2 huh ?

Comment: Is there any way to get 11 instead of 22 ? please let me know that

Comment: Try `var_dump`. All the information is *right there*, you should be able to debug this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks @meagar for your var_dump suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mysql_fetch_array() by default returns a combined associative AND indexed array structure.

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM table
```

will produce a row array of

```
$row = array(0 => 'value of a', 'a' => 'value of a', 1 => 'value of b', etc...);
```

You can force it to do one or the other by specifying the optional fetch_mode parameter:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH); // default mode
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC); // same as mysql_fetch_assoc: associative array
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM); // same as mysql_fetch_row: indexed array
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array returns 2 colums per column.

For example:

```
array(
    [0] => '1.jpg',
    ['one'] => '1.jpg'
    etc..
```

if you do `mysql_query($query,MYSQL_ASSOC)` you will get the `['one']` only.

Check this documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

If you look into documentation of [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), you will see a second parameter:

```
$result_type = MYSQL_BOTH
```

It means that, function returns merged arrays with associative keys and numeric keys too.

So you have doubled data.

You can avoid it with:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

or just:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

a magic link: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

your table setup doesn't seem quite sensible, by the way.

Comment: I dont really know the way to do I just thought to do , please tell me what is the best way to save pictures under one user?

Comment: I see no point in having such a table at all. why do you want to save picture names? can't you read them from the directory?

Comment: @col: could be uploaded images with meta-data in the DB and file on the drive.

Comment: Directory ? we need to save the information in the database right ? I mean websites save the pictures in the database in these way does not they ? websites that allows you upload your pictures they keep track of file path right? please correct me if im wrong

Comment: well for the some coomplicated cases - yes, but storing just these numbers 1,2,3... makes no sense for me.

Comment: @MarcB STILL there should be different setup for this, a sensible one. one-to-many table, you know. not these silly 1.jpg  2.jpg  3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc), you'll only have `$row['one']` and no more `$row[1]`.